# Express Session does not save with custom DNS address

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, twitter-oauth, express-session

I am trying to log in using Twitter's authentication. Express-session saves the tokens within the /twitterlogin route perfectly fine when I use localhost:8080, or with the ec2 link and the tokens are still there when the /twitterAuthenticated route is hit on the callback. However when I use the custom address (www.myaddress.org) the session does not remember the tokens I saved when it reaches the /twitterAuthenticated callback route.

Here's my configuration with comments on where the issues arise:

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var secrets = require('./backend/secrets.js');
var router = require('./backend/routes.js');

var app = express();
module.exports.app = app;

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

// Serving static files from main directory.
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));

//middleware
app.use(cors())

app.use(session({
    secret: secrets.sessionSecret,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
    }
}));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Set up backend routes
app.use("/", router);

app.listen(app.get("port"));
console.log("Listening on", app.get("port"));
```

And my routes:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var path = require('path');
var cors = require('cors');

var secrets = require('./secrets.js');
// Twitter integration
var twitterAPI = require('node-twitter-api');
var twitter = new twitterAPI({
    consumerKey: secrets.consumerKey,
    consumerSecret: secrets.consumerSecret,
    //Changing this callback is what causes the issue. Works fine with the two first ones that are commented out here, ec2, and localhost:8080
    // callback: 'http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/twitterAuthenticated'
    // callback: 'http://localhost:8080/twitterAuthenticated'
    //However it is this callback that does not save the session data. I've tried changing this to mywebsitename.org:8080 and even the elastic IP address to no result
    callback: 'http://mywebsitename.org/twitterAuthenticated'

});
router.get('/', function(request, response) {
    if (request.session.twitterData && request.session.twitterData.signedIn) {
        console.log("server.js - Serve index page - User Signed in")
        twitter.verifyCredentials(request.session.twitterAccess.accessToken, request.session.twitterAccess.accessTokenSecret, function(error, data, res) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("+++ 21 server.js error: ", error)
            } else {
                response.status(202)
                    .sendFile(path.resolve("app/index.html"));
            };
        })
    } else {
        console.log("server.js - Serve index page - User NOT SIGNED IN")
        request.session.twitterData = {};
        request.session.twitterData.signedIn = false;
        response.status(202)
            .sendFile(path.resolve("app/index.html"));
    }
});
//login to Twitter route
router.get('/twitterlogin', function(request, response) {
    console.log("+++ 37 routes.js at /twitterlogin")
    if (request.session.twitterData && request.session.twitterData.signedIn) {
        console.log("+++ 39 routes.js twitter data present already, redirect to /")
        response.redirect('/')
    } else {
        twitter.getRequestToken(function(error, requestToken, requestTokenSecret, results) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error getting OAuth request token : " + error);
                request.session.twitterData = {
                    signedIn: false
                };
                response.sendStatus(404)
            } else {
                request.session.regenerate(function() {
                    console.log("+++ 50 routes.js /twitterlogin success")
                    //This data saves fine with localhost and ec2 link but not with my custom dns link (http://mywebsitename.org)
                    request.session.twitterRequest = {
                        twitterRequestToken: requestToken,
                        twitterRequestTokenSecret: requestTokenSecret
                    }
                    request.session.twitterData = {
                        signedIn: true
                    };
                    request.session.save();
                    //return data to frontend for redirect (NOTE: response.redirect() does not work from backend with twitter. Gets CORS error
                    response.status(200).json({ "requestToken": requestToken, "requestTokenSecret": requestTokenSecret, "results": results })
                })
            }
        });
    }
});
//Route hit when arriving back from Twitter authentication page
router.get('/twitterAuthenticated', function(request, response) {
    console.log("+++ 67 routes.js at /twitterAuthenticated")
     //Here is where the request.session shows the tokens correctly if using localhost or ec2 link but not with my custom DNS address  (http://mywebsitename.org)
    console.log("+++ 68 routes.js request: ", request.session)
   twitter.getAccessToken(request.session.twitterRequest.twitterRequestToken, request.session.twitterRequest.twitterRequestTokenSecret, request.query.oauth_verifier, function(error, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, results) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("+++ 73 routes.js Success at /twitterAuthenticated. Redirect to /")
            request.session.twitterAccess = {
                accessToken: accessToken,
                accessTokenSecret: accessTokenSecret
            };
            request.session.twitterData.twitterUsername = results.screen_name;
            request.session.twitterData.userId = results.user_id;
            console.log("+++ 80 routes.js results: ", results)
            response.redirect('/')
        }
    })
});


module.exports = router;
```

I am using Angular for my frontend, if that helps. Any suggestions toward this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to authenticate your website with Twitter? Twitter may have white listed certain sites that are frequently used for testing, which is why it was working before

Comment: We do need twitter auth. We are using it to tweet to certain users, thus need to be logged in from the site. One thing is that it still works with the localhost and ec2 links. So I don't believe it is blacklisted.